# How to add elements to array in for loop, PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm connecting to 3 databases which are stored in array `$firmy`
For now they are hard coded into array but they will be set via Axios request.

```
public function show(Request $request, $division, $id)
{
    $firmy = array('connection1', 'connection2', 'connection3');
    $data = [];

    foreach ($firmy as $firma) {
        DB::setDefaultConnection($firma);

        $calendar = new CalendarEvent();
        $data[] = CalendarEventResource::collection($calendar->with('calendarCategories')->where('start', '>', '2020-05-21')->get());

        DB::purge($firma);
    }
    foreach ($data as $firma_event) {
        foreach ($firma_event as $event) {
            $eventT[] = $event;
        }
    }
    return $eventT;
}
```

I set the connection, get collection and close the connection.
3 times in this case.

Then I loop through the data to get all records in one go.
Here's the API response returned by `$eventT` array:

`[{"id":17549,"title":"Test","description":"test","contact":"test","email":"test","cat":1,"approved":0,"kto_dodal":450,"calendarCategories":{"id":1,"name":"Ogolna","color":"blue"},"start":"2020-09-30","end":"2020-09-30","private":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},`

`{"id":17580,"title":"Test","description":"test","contact":"test","email":"test","cat":1,"approved":0,"kto_dodal":450,"calendarCategories":{"id":1,"name":"Ogolna","color":"blue"},"start":"2020-09-30","end":"2020-09-30","private":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},`

`{"id":17545,"title":"Test","description":"test","contact":"test","email":"test","cat":1,"approved":0,"kto_dodal":450,"calendarCategories":{"id":1,"name":"Ogolna","color":"blue"},"start":"2020-09-30","end":"2020-09-30","private":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]`

One per each connection/table which is fine.

I would like to add a name of the connection to each record. So the API response would look like this:

`{"id":17545,"title":"Test","description":"test","contact":"test","email":"test","cat":1,"approved":0,"kto_dodal":450,"calendarCategories":{"id":1,"name":"Ogolna","color":"blue"},"start":"2020-09-30","end":"2020-09-30","private":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null, "firma":connection1}]`

So `"firma":nameOfConnection` added to each record.

I tried looping through the `data[]` and using `array_push` but I can't place the value of connection inside each record.
Value ends up outside of object:

`0: {id: 17549, title: "Test", description: "Test ",…} 1: {firma: "connection1"} firma: "connection1"`

Comment: I don't think you'll use `array_push` because you would simply be adding a new element to the array.  Instead, you want to add a new object attribute to an _existing_ array element.  Maybe change the line to something like:
```
$result = CalendarEventResource::collection(...etc...)->get());
$result->firma = $firma";
$data[] = $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try this approach but it doesn't add `firma` to the collection.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to include the code that you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, there it is: `$result = CalendarEventResource::collection($calendar->with('calendarCategories')->where('start', '>', '2020-05-21')->get());
            $result->firma = $firma;
            $data[] = $result;
            dd($data);` And here's the result of dd: ``array:1 [▼
  0 => Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection {#1287 ▼
    +collects: "App\Http\Resources\CalendarEventResource"
    +collection: Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1291 ▶}
    +resource: Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1291 ▶}
    +additional: []
    +"firma": "connection1"
  }
]``

Comment: Add it to your question so it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it.
First I added a value of `firma` to Resource class so it gets added to collection although it will be `null` because there is no column in DB with that name:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'                    => $this->id,
            'title'                 => $this->title,
            'description'           => $this->description,
            'contact'               => $this->contact,
            'email'                 => $this->email,
            'cat'                   => $this->cat,
            'approved'              => $this->approved,
            'kto_dodal'             => $this->kto_dodal,
            'calendarCategories'    => new CalendarCategoryResource($this->whenLoaded('calendarCategories')),
            'start'                 => $this->start,
            'end'                   => $this->end,
            'private'               => $this->private,
            'created_at'            => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at'            => $this->updated_at,
            'firma'                 => $this->firma,
        ];
    }
```

Then I access Event collection,loop through the results and set value of `firma` to whatever value the loop is currently at.

```
public function show(Request $request, $division, $id)
    {
        $firmy = array('connection1', 'connection2', 'connection3');
        $data = [];

        foreach ($firmy as $firma) {
            DB::setDefaultConnection($firma);

            $calendar = new CalendarEvent();
            $data = CalendarEventResource::collection($calendar->with('calendarCategories')
                ->where('start', '>', '2020-09-21')
                ->where('private', '=', '0')
                ->get());

            // Loop over data in collection and set value of firma
            foreach ($data as $value) {
                $value->firma = $firma;
                $total[] = $value;
            }

            DB::purge($firma);
        }

        return $total;
    }
```

Here's the returned value with the attribute `firma` inside the object:

```
{"id":17545,"title":"Test","description":"test","contact":"test","email":"test","cat":1,"approved":0,"kto_dodal":450,"calendarCategories":{"id":1,"name":"Ogolna","color":"blue"},"start":"2020-09-30","end":"2020-09-30","private":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"firma":"connection1"},
```